# Python parse Matrix style string with empty cells into two dimensional list

Tags: python, parsing, matrix, split

I have such an output received from paramiko SSH and I am trying to turn this into a list of lists (two dimensional list):

```
===============================================================================
Card State
===============================================================================
Slot/  Provisioned      Equipped         Admin Operational   Num   Num Comments
Id     Type             Type             State State         Ports MDA         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      iom-sar          iom-sar          up    up                  6           
1/1    a16-chds1        a16-chds1        up    up            16                
1/2    a8-ethv2         a8-ethv2         up    up            8                 
A      csm-1g           csm-1g           up    up                      Active  
B      csm-1g           csm-1g           up    up                      Standby 
===============================================================================
```

This is returned as a single string. I can divide the lines with splitline() however I cannot detect the columns because there are some empty values and I cannot make Python understand how to distinguish empty cells from spaces between cells.

For instance the first line that starts with "1      iom-sar " should be divided into 8 cells like the title column "Slot/  Provisioned      Equipped         Admin Operational   Num   Num Comments"

I had an idea of finding the title colums, somehow finding the beginning of each title and since each line value is aligned with title values, divide accordingly. Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the Python code you have tried.

Comment: This output is human-readable but not very computer-friendly. Perhaps you can find a way to get more computer-friendly output.

Comment: I have realized the format was messed up and changed it to appear correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is the solution that I came up with so far:

First split the string line by line by using

```
a=output_string.splitline()
```

Iterate over the list a, split it at the spaces and count the list elements (in order to find the longest length to find the number of columns. Store the line number of the line with most elements (aka. title line or a full line)

```
longest_line=0
length=0
for i in range(len(a)):
   if len(a.split())>length:
      length=len(a.split())
      longest_line=i
```

Split the title line into a list

```
b=a[longest_line].split()
```

Find the start positions of each title element and store with

```
startpositions=[]
for i in b:
    startpositions.append(a.find(i))
```

Slice the lines from the start positions

```
for i in startpositions:
   final_list.append(a[i:i+1])
```

This is like a psudo-code/algorithm. This will not work, there are index issues and the lists and declarations can be optimized I believe.